# Can the "Ghost" card of in BANG! The Valley of Shadows double the elimination reward

Tags: bang

Can I get the 3 card reward twice by eliminating an player, then using a ghost card on them, and discarding the ghost card?

[image: The Fantasma(Ghost) card]

The rules for the ghost card read

> A ghost is considered “in play” for all
> purposes, but has no life points: At the end of
> your turn, you must discard all your hand cards.
> If Ghost is removed, the ghost exits play again.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the Ghost card?

Comment: Did you play this expansion before, it hard to explain. Normal rule is any player eliminate outlaw will get 3 card . The "Ghost" card will bring player who is eliminated back to the game untill this card is steal or discard. My situation is after i eliminate outlaw and get the reward then i use ghost card on him and discard it (meaning i revive him and eliminate him again), I can get the reward one more time ?

Comment: I don't know if I played it, however you are able to put the text that is on the card which could help others understand what you are asking about.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, unlike the *Ghost Town* event, bringing a player back with the "Ghost" card and then removing the card will not give additional rewards.

This was cleared up by the official DV Games account on [boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2119446/article/30821766#30821766), stating

> short answer: No, you don't get to draw cards when removing a Ghost card from an already eliminated player.
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> Martino Chiacchiera
> Junior Editor